# I want to get the results of a python program emailed to me

Tags: python

I’m using repl to code with python and I’ve just designed a would you rather game. I want the answers that people submit to be emailed to me. I can get a variable that contains all the answers but am not sure as to how to call an email function.

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for "python email howto"?

Comment: It would be nice if you could show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

There exist several tutorials online about how to do this.

I've used [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-emails-in-python-with-smtp--cms-29975) in the past and found it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I send emails through Python using Gmail. First, you have to let "less secure apps" access your account, as described here:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Then I use this function to send email with a subject, body, and attachment.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def send_email(to_address,
               subject,
               body,
               from_address,
               password_of_sender,
               attachment_file=None):
    """
    Send an email wtith attachment using a Gmail account as the sender.
    """    
    # instance of MIMEMultipart
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_address
    msg['To'] = to_address
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    # attach the body with the msg instance
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    if attachment_file:
        # open the file to be sent
        attachment = open(attachment_file, "rb")
        # instance of MIMEBase and named as p
        p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        # To change the payload into encoded form
        p.set_payload((attachment).read())
        # encode into base64
        encoders.encode_base64(p)
        p.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                    'attachment; filename= %s' % attachment_file)
        # attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg'
        msg.attach(p)

    # creates SMTP session
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587, timeout=30)
    # start TLS for security
    s.starttls()
    # Authentication
    s.login(from_address, password_of_sender)
    # Converts the Multipart msg into a string
    text = msg.as_string()
    # sending the mail
    s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, text)
    # terminating the session
    s.quit()



send_email('send_to_address@gmail.com', 'SUBJECT', 'BODY   ...', 'sent_from@gmail.com', 'sent_from_password')
```